# How to make the NSAlert's 2nd button the return button?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsalert

I'd like to make something like this `NSAlert`:
[image]

As you can see, the 'return' button is the second one. How can I do this? 
Here's an example of the code that I use to create my `NSAlert`, but the first button gets the focus:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setMessageText:@"Are you sure you want to disconnect?"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Disconnect"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert runModal];
```

I want to focus the "Cancel" button. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in this cocoa-dev thread: [Making the correct button the default button?](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/96603-making-the-correct-button-the-default-button.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To change the key equivalents for the `NSButton` elements inside of the `NSAlert` object, you'll have to access the buttons directly (after creation and before `-runModal`) and change the key equivalents using the `-setKeyEquivalent:` method.

For example, to set the `Disconnect` to be ESC and the `Cancel` to be return, you would do the following:

```
NSArray *buttons = [alert buttons];
// note: rightmost button is index 0
[[buttons objectAtIndex:1] setKeyEquivalent: @"\033"];
[[buttons objectAtIndex:0] setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];
```

before calling `-runModal`

Comment: The right most button("Disconnect") is at index 0. Its key is "\r" i.e. return, not ESC. I may get it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let alert = NSAlert()
alert.messageText = question
alert.informativeText = text
alert.alertStyle = .critical
let deleteButton = alert.addButton(withTitle: "Delete")
let cancelButton = alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
deleteButton.keyEquivalent = ""
cancelButton.keyEquivalent = "\r"
```